# A cross-origin error was thrown while working on asynchronous http calls using react-thunk in codesandbox.io

Tags: reactjs, api, react-redux, react-thunk

I am  practicing on API calls using react-thunk. but i am getting the following error.

> proxyConsole.js:64 Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React
>   doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.

For practicing purpose i have referred this following link[React-redux-tutorial](https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/react-redux-tutorial-part-iii-async-redux/)

I have practiced the code in codesandbox.io. code will be available in [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/crud-operations-04mr4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandbox console doesn't always gives you the full error.

However, if you open the actual browser console, you can see the full error.

[image]

The error is that **Provider is not imported properly from react-redux**

`import Provider from "react-redux";` needs to be written as `import { Provider } from "react-redux";` to fix the same